# Pass array value in URL, http_build_query Not giving required results

Tags: php, curl, query-string

I'm looking for script that can encode array values for keys.  I need pass array value not key array for multiple values.

`http_build_query`  will produce output like below:

```
&viewColumns%5B0%5D=date&viewColumns%5B1%5D=adv_responses
```

I need output like below:

```
&viewColumns=%5B%22date%22%2C%22adv_responses%22%5D
```

Please let me know if there is any solutions, the code is like this:

```
$data= array();
$data['group']  = 'cpcReportsAdvertiser';
$data['dimensions']  = array('date');
$data['viewColumns']  = array('date','adv_responses');
// $data['measures']  = ["adv_responses"];
$date = array('between',array('2019-07-01','2019-07-31'));
$dates = new stdClass; 
$dates->date= $date;
$data['filters']  = $dates;
$data['attributes']  = [];

$sort = new stdClass; 
$sort->column = 'adv_impressions'; 
$sort->direction = 'asc'; 
$data['sort']  = $sort;
$data['limit']  = 50;

$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));

print_r($url);exit;
```

Comment: No As it is GET request, There is requirements to call third party api, It works well in Postman, But in PHP I didn't find any relative solution.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

To get `viewColumns=%5B%22date%22%2C%22adv_responses%22%5D&` which decodes to `viewColumns=["date","adv_responses"]` you would need to `json_encode` it:

```
$data['viewColumns']  = json_encode(array('date','adv_responses'));
```